# VirtualBox can not run as normal user.

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I installed VirtualBox as administrator in windows 7, then I switch to a normal user, installed a Ubuntu in VirtualBox, it works fine for couple weeks, I usually use headless start virtual machine. But recently, I can not launch VirtualBox as a normal user anymore,either use command line or GUI,  whenever I launch VirtualBox I will get

`Completely failed to instantiate CLSID_VirtualBox: CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE.
CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005)
VirtualBoxClientWrap
IVirtualBoxClient {d2937a8e-cb8d-4382-90ba-b7da78a74573}`

I have tried reinstall VirtualBox, restart windows,  yeah, it just works like take a chance. The only reliable way to launch it is [run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462391/virtualbox-critical-error-windows-8), but I don't want this.